# Problems with installing packages in R 3.6.1

Tags: r, rtools

I am struggling with my R version (3.6.1). Many packages that I would like to install doesn't work because the message below:

```
install.packages("Rtools")

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘Rtools’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)
```

Any idea what's happening?

Comment: `Rtools` cannot be installed through `install.packages`. Instead follow the instructions given [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/). We don't know what other packages you are referring to.

Comment: @zx8754 The dupe target basically just re-iterates the link to the `Rtools` installation instructions. Hopefully that gets OP started. There are a few more posts around here involving issues with `Rtools` but they seem to be more specific.